# Check in an array of object 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have an array of an object say `ClientsDTO[]`. There is a property namely `Tin` in the object. I want to check if a value is present in the array. I have one way of checking this i.e. using the LINQ query and getting the list of objects which satisfies the condition. If the returned list is null then the value is not present in the array. If the list exists then value is present in the array. The following is a sample code.

I want to know is there a better way than this i.e. something more elegant and with better performance. I am using VS 2008, 3.5 framework.

```
ClientsDTO[] client = new ClientsDTO[10];

var lstclient = client.Where(c => c.TIN == anyNumber).FirstOrDefault();
if (lstclient == null)
{
    //value present in array
}
else
{
   //value not present
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @abatishchev: The question clearly says "I am using VS 2008, 3.5 framework". It was originally tagged with **C# 3.0**, which is not the same thing as .NET 3.0. I don't understand how either your edit or your comment applies.

Comment: @Cody: Thank you, and sorry. Anyway, be easier, nothing serious happened. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the overload of [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) that takes a predicate:

```
bool valueIsPresent = client.Any(c => c.TIN == anyNumber);
```

Comment: thx. The solution was staring at my face and i did not realize. :)